According to Catholicism who were the mandated leader(s) of the Old Covenant?
Who do Catholics believe that God put in charge of Judaism in the Old Covenant?  I assume they believe that there was someone in charge with continuity from the time of Moses to Christ and that they know who this was, or do they believe that it perhaps wasn't as cut and dried as in the New Covenant?  I am a bit confused because I have heard a number of figures mentioned such as the Sanhedrin, judge (Dt. 17:9), priesthood, High Priest, etc.  Two things to consider are that neither Moses nor Joshua were priests and that presumably the Pharisees of Mt. 23:2 weren't priests either.

I'm not a Catholic, but I'll just note that if you follow the scriptural narrative, the person designated to lead the people changed overtime. Moses designated Joshua to lead the people into Israel in his stead. After Joshua, God would raise up various Judges from time to time as needed. Eventually, the people cried out and demanded a King - rejecting God - and so he gave them Saul and then David and Solomon, etc. And, of course, God continued to send prophets to the people and to the kings - particularly when they became corrupt and abandoned the Covenant.

According to Catholicism who were the mandated leader(s) of the Old Covenant?
The  Jewish High Priests , although holding a certain amount of influence in Jewish culture and leadership, were there to guild the Jewish people and pray for the nation of God’s people.
The Jewish Sanhedrin was more or less simply the supreme council and court of justice among the Jews. Thus the held great influence in certain Jewish circles, the Sanhedrin did not have any leadership roles in Jewish government.

After the exile, Israel's monarchial form of government had become a thing of the past; in its place the Jews created a community which was half State, half Church.

According to the Catholicism, the Old Testament leaders were as follows:

Moses: He lead Israel out slavery and governed the Jewish people through 40 years of wondering through the desert and into the Promised Land. He established, what we now call the Mosaic Legislation for the people of Israel.

Joshua Chosen to succeed Moses by Moses himself as judge and leader of the People of God.


In the New Testament, St. Paul himself mentions the judges in their proper place between Josue and Samuel (Acts 13:20); he praises some of the judges along with certain kings (Hebrews 11:32).

Samuel: Under the Prophet and last of the Judges, Samuel, the people of Israel demanded a king and Samuel reluctantly yielded to their request.

After the judges, God permitted Israel to be lead by kings

Saul First King of Israel.

David: The second king of Israel, the great-grandson of Boaz and Ruth (Ruth 4:18 sqq.)

Solomon Third King of Israel.



After Solomon’s death, his son Rehoboam was set to become the next king. Jeroboam returned from Egypt and led a group of people to confront Rehoboam with a demand for a lighter tax burden. When Rehoboam refused the demand, ten of the tribes rejected Rehoboam and David’s dynasty (1 Kings 12:16), and Ahijah’s prophecy was fulfilled. Only Judah and Benjamin remained loyal to King Rehoboam. The northern tribes crowned Jeroboam as their king. Rehoboam made plans to mount an assault on the rebel tribes, but the Lord prevented him from taking that action (vv. 21-24). Meanwhile, Jeroboam further consolidated his power by instituting a form of calf worship unique to his kingdom and declaring that pilgrimages to Jerusalem were unnecessary. Thus, the people of the northern tribes would have no contact with the tribes of Judah and Benjamin. - Why was Israel divided into the Southern Kingdom and Northern Kingdom?

For a Catholic Chronology of the Kings under the Kingdom of Israel and the Kingdom of Judea see here.
After the death of the last of the kings, God raised up several lesser Prophets to lead Israel, the last being Malachias or Malachi (430 BC).
The Pharisees were a politico-religious sect or faction among the adherents of later Judaism, that came into existence as a class about the third century B.C.
In the 2nd century BC, God raise the priestly family of the Maccabees  under the leadership of Mathathias to free Israel against the tyranny of Antiochus IV of the Seleucid Empire.

The persecution proved a blessing in disguise; it exasperated even the moderate Hellenists, and prepared a rebellion which freed the country from the corrupting influences of the extreme Hellenist party. The standard of revolt was raised by Mathathias, as priest of the order of Joarib (cf. 1 Chronicles 24:7), who to avoid the persecution had fled from Jerusalem to Modin (now El Mediyeh), near Lydda, with his five sons John, Simon, Judas, Eleazar and Jonathan. When solicited by a royal officer to sacrifice to the gods, with promises of rich rewards and of the king's favour, he firmly refused, and when a Jew approached the altar to sacrifice, he slew him together with the king's officer, and destroyed the altar. He and his sons then fled to the mountains, where they were followed by many of those who remained attached to their religion. Among these were the Hasîdîm, or Assideans, a society formed to oppose the encroaching Hellenism by a scrupulous observance of traditional customs. Mathathias and his followers now overran the country destroying heathen altars, circumcising children, driving off aliens and apostate Jews, and gathering in new recruits. He died, however, within a year (166 B.C.). At his death he exhorted his sons to carry on the fight for their religion, and appointed Judas military commander with Simon as adviser. He was buried at Modin amid great lamentations (1 Maccabees 2). - The Machabees


Judas Machabeus (166-161 BC)

Jonathan (161-143 BC)

Simon (143-135 BC)

John Hyrcanus (135-105 BC)

Aristobulus I (105-104 BC)

Alexander Jannæusn (104-78 BC)

The last Machabees (78-37 BC)



Alexander bequeathed the government to his wife Alexandra Salome, and the high-priesthood to his son Hyrcanus II. She ruled in accordance with the wishes of the Pharisees. At her death (69 B.C.) civil war broke out between Hyrcanus II and his brother Aristobulus II. This brought on Roman interference and loss of independence (63 B.C.). Hyrcanus, whom the Romans recognized as ethnarch, was ruler only in name. Aristobulus was poisoned in Rome by the adherents of Pompey, and his son Alexander was beheaded at Antioch by order of Pompey himself (49 B.C.). Antigonus, the son of Aristobulus, was made king by the Parthians; but the next year he was defeated by Herod with the aid of the Romans, and beheaded at Antioch (37 B.C.). With him ended the rule of the Machabees. Herod successively murdered (a) Aristobulus III, the grandson of both Aristobulus II and Hyrcanus II through the marriage of Alexander, the son of the former, with Alexandra, the daughter of the latter (35 B.C.); (b) Hyrcanus II (30 B.C.) and his daughter Alexandra (28 B.C.); (c) Mariamne, the sister of Aristobulus III (29 B.C.); and lastly his own two sons by Mariamne, Alexander and Aristobulus (7 B.C.). In this manner the line of the Machabees became extinct. - The Machabees

Thus all was prepared in a mystical and historical sense for the arrival of the true Messiah that will lead the People of God to a new and more glorious Kingdom in Heaven and who's birth was situated by historians between 6-4 BC. Jesus was born in Bethlehem Judea of the Virgin Mary ...

The question confuses civil authority with religious authority.
The tribe of Levi was responsible for running ancient Israel's religious system, and within that tribe the Priesthood was responsible for conducting sacrifices etc., with the High Priest being the leader.
Their duties were mandated and defined by the Levitical Laws given in the Torah.
The Judges, Kings, etc. were leaders of the civil system, as mandated and defined by the Civil Laws given in the Torah.
(A third set of laws defined in the Torah, is the Moral Law (e.g. Ten Commandments). Following these laws was one of the requirements of the "Old Covenant", but they are not specific to it. They are general laws for all time (E.g. Abraham followed them).)
The ten tribes of northern Israel were taken into captivity by the Assyrians, and later the southern tribes (Judah and Benjamin) were occupied by Rome.
Under foreign control, there was no longer any need for a Jewish civil leader or government, and the Civil Laws were no longer required.
Similarly, following the Roman's destruction of the Temple and Priesthood in A.D. 70, all religious aspects of life were maintained by the Pharisees, who are effectively today's Rabbis.
Note that unlike Catholicism, which has a strong central leadership in Rome, modern Judaism is widely distributed and has no central leader.
The Torah defines what is expected of Jews, and that never changes, so there is no need for decision making or the creation of new laws.
CATHOLIC ENCYCLOPEDIA: Judaism says:

The Creator of heaven and earth, in His mercy towards fallen man (Genesis 1-3), had made a covenant with their father Abraham, in virtue of which his seed, and in his seed all the peoples of the earth, should be blessed (Genesis 12, 18; II Esdras 9). From that time forth, He had watched over them with jealous care. The other nations, once fallen into idolatry, He had allowed to grovel amid their impure rites; but He had dealt differently with the Israelites whom he wished to be unto Him "a priestly kingdom and a holy nation" (Exodus 19:6). Their repeated falls into idolatry He had not left unpunished, but He kept alive among them the revealed religion which ever represented God as the true and adequate object of their devotion, trust, gratitude, of their obedience and service.

Clearly, God wanted Israel (and Judah) to be a holy nation first, and administered by the Priesthood.

To be fair, Israel as a nation was a theocracy. The first leader (Moses) served as both ruler and priest, and the scriptures themselves denounce the people when they eventually demand a king. And those kings were in turn anointed by God. It thus isn’t improper to speak of religious and political power together - because the scriptural narrative doesn’t strictly separate them either.

This question does not answer Who do Catholics believe that God put in charge of Judaism in the Old Covenant

@AviAvraham, is there any reason to think that Catholics believe someone other than the High Priest was "in charge" of the religion? I've added Catholic citation.

So the modern Jewish claim that rabbis have always been the religious leaders of Judaism is false? But then how do you explain Matthew 23:2?

@wmasse asks: "So the modern Jewish claim that rabbis have always been the religious leaders of Judaism is false?" — It depends upon what "always" means. As I said: "following the Roman's destruction of the Temple and Priesthood in A.D. 70, all religious aspects of life were maintained by the Pharisees, who are effectively today's Rabbis.". Before that, the High Priest was the top leader when it comes to making sacrifices and other duties and ceremonies. Matthew 23:2 means that the Rabbis work directly with the people and one should follow their guidance as they speak with authority.

@RayButterworth  So if I was living in 1000 BC and I wanted to know whether or not I could do something on the Sabbath I would ask a priest?

@wmasse, I don't know what you'd do in 1000 BC, but the Catholic Church will tell you that you definitely wouldn't have dealt with a Pharisee: "A politico-religious sect or faction among the adherents of later Judaism, that came into existence as a class about the third century B.C." — (CATHOLIC ENCYCLOPEDIA: Pharisees).

@RayButterworth  But how does Mt. 23:2 fit in with that?  Why doesn't he tell people to listen to the priests?

@wmasse asks "Why doesn't he tell people to listen to the priests?" — Because Israelite priests weren't the same as Catholic priests. Personal advice and help can be requested of a Catholic priest, but that's not what Israelite priests did. Priesthood (ancient Israel) lists their duties, such as conducting ceremonies and offering sacrifices, but does not include personally interacting with the public.
